# В чём польза Mixin'ов?

Tags: ооп, mixins

Распишите пожалуйста, в чём польза использования миксинов, и как это решает проблему неоднозначности при использовании множественного наследования?

Answer (score 3):

Начнём с того, что в JS нет множественного наследования. Поэтому, в качестве одной из возможных альтернатив используются mixin-ы - объекты с определённым набором функций, которые не предназначены для самостоятельного применения.

С их помощью можно расширить возможности классов не перегружая объектную модель лишними методами. Также один и тот же mixin можно добавлять к различным классам, что нередко позволяет упростить "тиражирование" однотипного функционала между различными "ветвями" в "дереве" объектной модели.

К одному классу может быть добавлено сколько угодно mixin-ов.Только нужно следить, чтобы между ними не было конфликтов из-за имён методов.